# Ordinal Classification As Cost Function - In Keras or Tensorflow

Tags: classification, keras, tensorflow

I am having a hard time implementing/using an ordinal classification cost function for my Convolutional Neural Network in Tensorflow.

Any implementations/documentation/repository on that which you know of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst this question is now quite old, I was just looking for the same and came across this implementation for in Keras:

https://github.com/JHart96/keras_ordinal_categorical_crossentropy